# Secondary index is corrupt. The database must be defragmented

Tags: ravendb

Problem has appeared after DB restore. How I can repair DB?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Gengzu,
You probably moved the database between machines.
In order to resolve the problem, you need to run:

```
 esentutl /d Data
```

From the RavenDB data directory

Comment: What is the issue here? Can this be automated?

Comment: You probably moved the db between machines

Comment: Yes, so why does this require a manual step? What is esent/RavenDB tracking that is machine specific? What stops esent/RavenDB doing this step at startup?

Comment: TFD, it related to how the data is indexed with relation to your culture settings. We have a task to add it to RavenDB ops.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get: Operation terminated with error -1032 (JET_errFileAccessDenied, Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use) after 20.31 seconds.

Comment: @FerretallicA - I've run into the same issue after upgrading my azure instance from 2008 SP2 to 2008 R2. Have you solved the JET_errFileAccessDenied problem?

Comment: Didn't end up resolving it. It was a good push to look for alternatives where I found OrientDB which offers most of the benefits of RavenDB without any of the licensing catches.

Comment: Running "esentutl /d Data/Data" solved the -1032 error for me. Seems there is a file named "Data" inside of the directory named "Data" which is confusing things.

Comment: This happened for me after updating from Windows 8 to 8.1, and running the command in this answer solved the problem.

Comment: You need to do it for all databases in ravendb as well as for the system database

Comment: You might need to do this from a command problem with elevated privileges, especially if you're getting the -1032 error.  It fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should run the util from inside that Data folder in Raven. When I ran it in the root of Raven server -> "Operation terminated with error -1032..." also showed up.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open a command prompt as administrator
2. Change directory to RavenDB's *\Database\System* folder
3. Run the command below.

   esentutl /d Data

Comment: This was extremely useful - it's not obvious from any of the other answers from EXACTLY where to run this command

Comment: An important extra note. You may have to run this in your individual databases as well. RavenDB/Database/Databases/YourDatabaseName